# Why am I getting blank error messages in my Apache error log?

Tags: apache-2.2, perl

I am running Apache 2.2 on 64bit Windows Server 2008 Std edition with ActivePerl 5.8.9.  My error log is filling up with blank error messages like these:

> [Wed Mar 31 14:08:31 2010] [error] [client 10.6.1.164]
>
> [Wed Mar 31 14:10:32 2010] [error] [client 10.6.1.89]
>
> [Wed Mar 31 14:13:20 2010] [error] [client 10.6.1.131]

By looking in the access log I can tell that it occurs when our client machines issue a GET to a very simple Perl script.

```
#!perl.exe

use strict;
no warnings;

$|=1; 

use CGI::Carp('fatalsToBrowser');
use CGI qw(:standard);
print header;

my $CRLF = "\r\n<br>";
my $Port = '10116';     
print "Success!${CRLF}PollInterval=5${CRLF}LMProMode${CRLF}Version=7${CRLF}ConnectionPort=$Port";

exit;
```

The weird thing is that it does not look like this error message is inserted every time a GET to this Perl script occurs.  What could cause this error message to appear in the Apache error log?

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, but by default apache redirects anything writing to stderr out to the error.log file, so if your script was generating any stderr output at all (a space, a newline) that's how this might manifest.

Comment: I looked into that, but I don't think this script is doing that.  I know warns go to the stderr but I specify no warnings.

Comment: possibly turn it around then, turn off no-warnings and see if anything's causing one. Warnings will generally tell you if something non-standard's being done, which might help